# Structure of sentence with 喜欢+V

Tags: sentence-structure

I would know what is the correct place of 喜欢 in my sentence, or if the both are valids what are the differences.

1/ 我喜欢坐飞机去

2/ 我坐飞机喜欢去

Comment: The 1st one is correct.

Comment: cf。CCG（ISBN：９７８－１－１－１３８－８４０１７－１）Ch.17 Verbs that take verbal or clausal objects This chapter deals with cognitive verbs and verbs of emotion。Though some of them can take noun objects, they tend to be followed by verbal or clausal objects ... 17.1 intention and aspiration: 准备、打算，决定，试图、企图、设法、要求、希望、盼望、渴望、期望，指望，立志、热心，忍不住１７。１。２ negative intentions:懒得、免得、省得、舍不得、后悔、讨厌、不屑、反对，犯不着１７。１。３ uncertain aspirations 幻想、妄想、恨不得、巴不得 group intentions：１７。１。４研究、讨论，商量、酝酿、策划、合计 １７。１。５voiced intentions： 建议、主张、宣布、说明、强调、发誓、保证、扬言

Comment: １７。１，６intentions put into practice：开始、继续、着手、抓紧、负责 １７。１。７ frustration and compulsion：停止、不堪、不宜、不便、不致、不禁、不敢、不屑、不由得、禁不住 １７。２ Attitudes 爱、喜欢、乐意、害怕、敢于、勇于、甘于、急于、善于、习惯、假装、适合１７。３ Knowing and thinking 记得、忘记、知道、相信、觉得，感到、认为、以为、估计、肯定、担心、怕、怀疑、同意、证明、断定 １７。４ Appearance and value: 好象、显得，不如，值得、不足、不见得、看起来、在于、有待
１７。５ Dummy verbs：（a）加以 （b）进行 （c）给予

Comment: @user6065 thx I'm sure this book will be veryusefull to me,
 what is the conclusion according to my question?

Comment: @Christophe Debove it confirms 1st comment and extends it to more verbs, anyhow why 2/?, 2/:"I am taking the plane and like to go", which likely is not the intended meaning

Comment: @user6065 ok thank, I thought 2/ was more as , I "in plane" like to go,

Comment: so if I put  我坐飞机喜欢看山水 in that case do it work? or will it be 我喜欢坐飞机看山水

Comment: The second one is not correct at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a comparison to English will help you remember:
我喜欢**坐飞机**去。(adverbial)
I like to travel **by plane**.
我喜欢**坐飞机**看风景。(still adverbial)
I like to watch scenery **by plane**.
However:
我喜欢**坐飞机**（，而不是坐火车）。(followed by nothing)
I like to **take planes**(, not trains).
I'm not sure if my explanation makes sense. Just for reference.

Comment: the question is to which verb，喜欢 or 去 the adverbial "坐飞机＂applies，since it applies to 去 it must be put immediately ahead of the latter，我坐飞机喜欢去 might mean ＂when taking the plane I like to go＂

Comment: It must be 去. Compared to English, you never say "I by taking a plane like to go".

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the second sentence is not complete, it's invalid.

If you mean "I enjoyed board a plane", then you should say "我喜欢坐飞机", not "去".

When you use "去", a destination should be described in your talking context.

"我喜欢步行去巴黎" means "I like to go to Paris by walk", means when I go to Paris, I like to go there by walk.

"我步行喜欢去巴黎" means "I like to walking to Paris", means when I'm take a walking, I like to walking to Paris.

For extending, you may also say,

"巴黎，我喜欢步行去", equals to "I like to go to Paris by walk".

"我喜欢步行，去巴黎", means I like walking, especially walking to Paris.

But, if you say "我去巴黎喜欢步行", this may lead to misunderstanding of these two meanings, this is because "去" may meaning either "When I'm on my way to Paris" or "When I'm arrived and in Paris", there must be complementary information in context.

However, when you want to say "喜欢", just use the same sequence in English --"I like (somebody or something)", "我喜欢某某", that's it.