# Does 我喜欢你上课 mean "I like your class" or something like "I like it when you go to class"?

Tags: translation, grammar

[YouDao.com](http://www.youdao.com/example/blng/eng/%E4%B8%8A%E8%AF%BE) (sourced from [BigEar.cn](http://www.bigear.cn/res-1679-7777700080311.html)) gives the example sentence:

> 我喜欢你上课
>   I like your class
>   <sub>Wǒ xǐhuān nǐ shàngkè</sub>

I'm not confident this translation is accurate.

Ordinarily [我上课](http://dict.youdao.com/w/%E6%88%91%E4%B8%8A%E8%AF%BE/) means "I am attending class", so 你上课 should mean "you are attending class".  Therefore, 我喜欢你上课 should mean "I like it when you go to class" (or something similar like "I'd like for you to attend class" or "I'd like you to go to class" or "I like that you go to class").

**Question**: Does 我喜欢你上课 mean "I like your class" or something like "I like it when you go to class"?

Comment: 我喜欢你上**的**课 = I like the class you go to

Comment: 我喜欢你上课 is a  **pivotal sentence** : object 你 of verb 喜欢 is subject of second verb 上课, I like that you come to (attend)  (or teach the) class
cf. excerpts from  ＂实用现代汉语语法＂ **兼语句**  ，pivotal sentences，兼语句的类别（一）表示使令意义的兼语句。在这种兼语句里，第一个动词是表示使令意义的，如＂使＂、＂让＂、＂叫＂、＂请＂、派＂、＂强迫＂等等，兼语后词语所表示的动作或状态是由第一个动词所表示的动作引起的。例如；他请我去，我们让他来我们这儿，老师叫我们念课文。领队派他去南方了。他不准人家发表相反的意见。。。。（二）表示称谓或认定意义的兼语句。这种兼语句的第一个动词表示称谓或认定意义，如＂称＂、＂叫＂、＂骂＂、＂选＂、＂选举＂、＂推选＂、＂ 认＂、＂认为＂等，兼语后面的动词多为＂做＂、＂为＂、＂当＂、＂是＂等。例如：我给他起了个小名叫南南。由于各国经常打仗，历史上称这一时期为战国。我认您做我的师傅吧！人家背后骂我是废物。  **（三）表示爱憎、好恶等意义的兼语句** 。在这类兼语句中，第一个动词多表示  **喜欢** 、夸奖、祝贺或厌恶、责罚等，如＂烦＂、

Comment: **喜欢** ＂、＂讨厌＂、＂爱＂、＂恨＂、＂嫌＂、＂佩服＂、＂钦佩＂、＂羡慕＂、＂称赞＂、＂夸＂、＂欣赏＂、＂赞扬＂、＂原谅＂、＂笑话＂、＂责备＂、＂怪＂、＂
＂骂＂等。兼语及其后的谓语表示原因。例如；大家埋怨他来晚了。我们原谅他年纪小，没经验。群众  **喜欢** 他办事公道。

Comment: instead of "pivotal sentence" some might simply say "object is subject-predicate phrase" 有主谓词组充当宾语, e.g. 他发现这里也有这种细菌。我知道他出国了。我人为你比他热情。 It seems interesting that bkrs has very many examples of 喜欢 but only with nouns or verbs as objects (no new subject),also 

see comments #2,3 ＂Verbs that take verbal or clausal objects＂ w/o a change of subject, of https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17053/structure-of-sentence-with-%e5%96%9c%e6%ac%a2v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 我喜欢你上课

Most of time, it means 我喜欢你上的课 "I like you to teach the class， instead the class is taught by other teachers".

It rarely means "I like you to take the class".

Comment: see my comment on Jason Swift's answer

Comment: @TangHo, It seems that I reach the consensus with Jason Swift. 你上课 could mean both taking lessons and giving lessons. However, 我喜欢你上课 would be taken as giving/teaching lessons by default (without other context).

Comment: In my answer, I wrote: "我喜欢你上的课" = "I like the class you go to". Since the subject '你' doesn't state it is referring to teacher or a student,  (teacher can go to the class to teach) Therefore   "我喜欢你教的课" or "我喜欢你讲的课"  should be preferred if you meant "I like the class you teach"

Comment: Even the phrase "I like your class" in the question is ambiguous, Is it "I like your class that you teach?" or " I like your class that you attend to?"

Comment: @TangHo If you say 我喜欢你上的课, I could be interpreted in both way(still tend to the class you teach). But 我喜欢你上课 without other context, I tend more to interpret it as the class you teach just like saying 我喜欢你(给我们)上课. I think the main reason is that we take 上课 as a verb.

Comment: In my comment , I also stated -- To use 上课 for "giving lessons" you have to write something like "李老师给我们上课" ---> "李老师上课" just sounds incomplete .  "我喜欢你上课"  also sounds incomplete

Comment: @TangHo, I agree that 我喜欢你上课 is not as natural as 我喜欢你上的课 or 我喜欢让你上课. But it's acceptable in spoken without any problems for understanding the meaning.

Comment: It all comes with context. A school girl can say 我喜欢你上课 to her boyfriend which certainly mean "I like you to go to class". But I agree that in a vacuum I would more likely interpret it as "I like you to teach the course", or "I like the course you are teaching"

Answer (score 1):

"我喜欢你上**的**课" = "I like the class you go to"

"我喜欢你上课" doesn't seem to be a complete sentence.

> *YouDao.com (sourced from BigEar.cn) gives the example sentence: 我喜欢你上课*

It means " I like you going to class".  Certainly not "I like your class"

Answer (score 1):

**上课** can mean both taking lessons and giving lessons, depending on whether the subject is a student or a teacher.

> Question: Does 我喜欢你上课 mean "I like your class" or something like "I like it when you go to class"?

Without any context, it can mean both, but the former one tends to be more common.

Comment: "teaching class"  is '授课' ; If you want to say "I like the class you teach" it should be "我喜欢你教的课"  or "我喜欢你讲的课" To use 上课 for "giving lessons" you have to write  something like "李老师**给**我们上课"

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, it's just a guessing game, but I would bet on:

我喜欢你上课。 (你很好伙子！)
I'm pleased (that) you go to class. (You're a good lad!)

http://www.zdic.net/c/c/72/114289.htm

喜欢(2) [happy;elated]∶愉快;高兴

The knee-jerk reaction 喜欢 == like may be misleading.

I like your class.
我喜欢你的课。
I'm glad you've come to class.
我很高兴你来上课！

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not really the common sense of most Chinese, especially in mainland.

Answer (score 1):

"我喜欢你上课" is usually said by teachers who would like you to attend class.But it is a little bit strange to say in this way. However, if you want to say 'I like your class' in chinese, you can say '我喜歡上你的課‘ instead. Which means you like and enjoy the class.

Answer (score 0):

"我喜欢你上课" isn't what people usually say, it's not complete and even confusing.

> “I like your class” (means you're the teacher) can be:
>
> 我喜欢你的课(I like your class)
>
> 我喜欢你上的课(I like the class you teach)
>
> 我喜欢上你的课(I like to go to your class)

-

> “I like it when you go to class” (means you're the classmate) can be:
>
> 我喜欢你来上课(I like you coming to the class)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this translation is more proper.

> 我喜欢你的课。
>   I like your class.

or

> 我喜欢上你的课。
>   I like attending your class.

---

**我**　 = I
**喜欢** = like
**上**　 = attending
**你的** = your
**课**　 = class